# Zweite Bedeutung von "Mehrwert"?

Tags: meaning

Ist die Bedeutung des Begriffes "Mehrwert" im Sinne von "Nutzen, Vorteil" geläufig und welche Nuance gibt es bei diesem Wort? z.B

> Da sehe ich keinen Mehrwert.

Comment: Marx: Gebrauchswert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Während *Nutzen* schon durch *Wert* allein abgedeckt wäre, steht das *Mehr* m. E. für einen Vergleich.

Die Alternative A, mit der verglichen wird, hat bereits einen Nutzen, der auch nicht in Frage gestellt wird. Die Variante B hat keinen *zusätzlichen Nutzen*, also keinen Mehrwert.

Answer (score 1):

Ja, man hört das manchmal, aber es ist eine ziemlich bürokratische Ausdrucksweise. (Wenn ich das höre, denke ich mir: Was für ein Widerling!)

Andere Ausdrücke, die alltagsnäher und meist auch freundlicher sind, wären

> Das bringt nichts.
>
> Das hat keinen Wert.
>
> Das hat keinen Sinn.
>
> Davon haben wir nichts.
>
> Das erfüllt den Zweck nicht.
>
> Das nützt nichts.
>
> Kannste knicken.
>
> Das ist fruchtlos / ein fruchtloses Unterfangen.
>
> Das lohnt den Aufwand nicht.
>
> Das lohnt die Mühe nicht.
>
> Das ist nicht der Mühe wert.
>
> Ach nee, lass mal!

Und viele andere mehr. Je nach Sprachregister und konkreter Situation natürlich.